# How to define differentiation of a time-dependent vectors with respect to a specific reference frame in a coordinate-free manner?

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, vectors, differentiation

It is usual in classical mechanics to introduce the derivative of a time-dependent vector with respect to a reference frame. This is accomplished through the use of a basis that is fixed with respect to that reference frame, so that, if a vector can be expressed as:

$$u = u_1e_1+u_2e_2+u_3e_3,$$

where $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ is a basis fixed with respect to a reference frame $R$, its derivative with respect to that reference frame is, by definition,

$$ \left.{\dot{u} }\right]_R = \dot{u_1}e_1+\dot{u_2}e_2+\dot{u_3}e_3.$$

This definition makes intuitive sense, as it measures how the reference frame $R$ "sees" the vector derivative. But its dependency on a basis and coordinates make it seem as if there must be a more fundamental way of defining this derivative, with concepts from Euclidean space that don't rely on coordinates. I haven't found nor been able to come up with a sensible definition though. So, how should one define it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will find more intuitive definition, because it's simple as it gets - sum of $N$ orthogonal vectors, which you can differentiate or integrate or whatever :
$$\vec u = \sum_i^N u_i \hat e_{\perp i} \tag 1$$

Differentiating (1):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac {d}{dx} \vec u &= \frac {d}{dx} \left(\sum_i^N u_i \hat e_{\perp i}\right)\\
                     &= \sum_i^N \frac {d}{dx}  u_i \hat e_{\perp i}\\
                     &=\sum_i^N \hat e_{\perp i} \frac {d u_i}{dx}
\end{align}
\tag 2
$$

In other words, it's just differentiation of vector addition procedure. Vector addition in vector spaces is same everywhere, with the difference that we add here orthogonal vectors. And that's it.

Comment: It isn't the algebraic realization of differentiation of vectors or the product rule that led me to ask this question, I have no issue with that - or with the intuition. It is the specific concept of differentiation with respect to a reference frame. A reference frame, as far as I know, doesn't need to be defined in terms of a vector basis. So the operation of differentiation with respect to a reference frame probably shouldn't depend on the definition of a basis, since a vector in a vector space isn't tied to any one representation given by a specific basis.

Comment: It's not about differentiation, but any vector representation in $3D$ Euclidean space of chosen reference frame. This is usually done by choosing a fixed origin in a reference frame and thee orthogonal bases unit vectors going from origin. Then we take some input vector and split it into three projections along these orthogonal unit vectors. If you add these, you'll get original vector in that reference frame. Likewise, any position on the Earth is described by a pair of projections into longitude and latitude orthogonal axis. So a reference frame is best represented by orthogonal vector set.